Do both sides of a frameless shower door need to be supported by studs?
Originally, I bought a frameless hinge/pivot tub door, but found out only one side of our tub had a stud while the other is just hollow Sheetrock. Of course, the stud is on the side where the toilet is so the door needs to be on the opposite end.
I'm now looking at sliding doors and would prefer a style with exposed top rollers. Is it correct to assume that the frameless style sliding doors would also not work since one end won't be supported by a stud? If so, would one of these options work for my situation?

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Basco-Rotolo-60-in-x-57-in-Semi-Frameless-Sliding-Bathtub-Door-in-Matte-Black-RTLH05B6057CLWI/309863591

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Delta-Contemporary-60-in-W-x-58-3-4-in-H-Frameless-Sliding-Bathtub-Door-in-Matte-Black-with-1-4-in-Tempered-Clear-Glass-SD6765039321849091



If you have access to the other side of the studless wall (e.g. it's a bedroom or hallway), it would cost you far less to simply remove some drywall, add a stud or blocking, repair the drywall, and continue installation of the tub door you already have to the new stud, than it would be to buy a new door.
If the other side of the wall is someone else's home (e.g. condo, townhome), obviously that won't work.  I'm assuming your problem is that the wall in the bathroom is already tiled and you don't want to fool with that.

Your #2 post shows not available to me, but the #1 that is semi frameless will be able to be used.
Any semi frameless, or slider with vertical metal on both ends supports the weight. You will need some proper drywall anchors for the wall with no studs.   Many kits come with their own drywall anchors, but I prefer plastic round head anchors. The kit anchors are often inferior. I throw them out.
